# C# .net - Web Camera Image Capture

Tags: c#, camera

I was wondering whether anyone knew of a good tutorial for Capturing an Image/Video stream from a web camera using C#?

Any suggestion would be a appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a tutorial for [EMGU Camera capture in 7 lines of code](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code).

Setup of the EMGU library is fairly easy to do, and the capturing of the camera is truly that easy.

Answer (score 7):

[EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial#C.23) is a good wrapper around the OpenCV API. There's a number of tutorials in the link.

Answer (score 4):

i use [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/).. Look at [this sample](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/directshow_video.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Microsoft Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Encoder4_Overview.aspx)

Sample project for recording from a live source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724701(v=Expression.40).aspx

Comment: I'm looking for some examples so I can write my own application. I realise such programs already exist but this is for a personal project. Thanks.

Comment: The Expression Encoder SDK is available in a free version and is quite usable for personal projects.