# Getting input from webcam

Tags: c#, .net, webcam

Does .NET have a native support for getting input from webcam?
If not, what is the best/recommended way to get input from webcam using C#/.NET?

Comment: I believe Silverlight 3.0 and beyond has an API for webcams. Is there a particular thing you are trying to do with the webcam?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108554/c-net-web-camera-image-capture

Comment: @tomasmcguinness: Silverlight 4 introduced webcam API.

Comment: My mistake @Neil. I forget we're on the verge of Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET does not have a native support for webcams. You can use [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) library. Also a .NET wrapper exists for OpenCV - [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: Just tried this. Seems to work except that it seems to require 1gb of additional files which is a non-solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to look at the easywebcam codeplex project:

http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/

On the other hand, the "native" option is to develop this using DirectShow. However, there is no (as far as I know), official managed interface for DirectShow, so it can have a steep learning curve to develop with.

Answer (score 2):

This was also asked in [How to get web cam images in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881858/how-to-get-web-cam-images-in-c) and you might find the following useful:

I've just released the complete sourcecode of my Windows app CamTimer (written in .NET/C#). Download/view the complete code (with working Webcam examples) at https://github.com/johanssonrobotics/CamTimer

Happy coding!

Comment: what a great application!

Answer (score 2):

There is also an SDK called MetriCam. It is supposed for Kinect and Time-of-Flight cameras, but also supports webcams. You can download it for free at http://www.metricam.net

It includes samples and tutorials how to integrate a DirectShow webcam into C#/.NET The webcam tutorial can be watched here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvnRpby8mSE