# Web Camera Capture

Tags: c#, webcam, emgucv

As the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108554/c-sharp-net-web-camera-image-capture) States, I am trying to capture an image with my web-camera. I am running Windows 7 (bootcamp) and have a camera connected as seen in the following screen capture.

[image: Screen shot showing devices]

But for some reason I can't seem to get the following code to work (it's from the [link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code) given in the other question):

```
Capture capture = new Capture(CaptureType.ANY); //fezzes on this line
viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
```

It dies with out telling me anything about what happened (after I force close the window)

Comment: What do you mean "it dies"?  Is there a runtime error that is thrown?  If so, what is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks questionable take a look at the Cameracapture example provided with EMGU I do not now where you get **CaptureType.ANY** from but your code should be

```
Capture capture = new Capture(); 
viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
```

While the link is valid it's old and outdated (2009).

Here is the slightly edited code from the example that you will need:

```
private Capture _capture;

public YOUR_PROJECT()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
        _capture = new Capture();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
    }

    if (_capture != null)
    {
        Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
    }
}


private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
    Picturebox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap(); //Display image in standard Picture Box
}
```

You only need to add a variable to the ***Capture capture = new Capture()*** method call if you have more than one camera or if your reading from a video file

```
//For example if I had two video Cameras
Capture capture = new Capture(0); //CAM1
Capture capture = new Capture(1); //CAM2

//For a Video File
Capture capture = new Capture(@"C:/..../Myvideofile.avi");
```

I hope this helps you out if not try with a USB camera to ensure it's not a conflict with EMGU (OpenCV) not being able to access the device.

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_capture = new Capture(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CaptureType.DSHOW);
```

This works great for me.